# C++ vectors - Is there any way I can copy a vector inside a for loop and use it outside of the loop?

Tags: c++

I have a do-while loop which copies a vector before it clears it, to make room for the for loop to run again. I have tried the following (with declaring the vector as a global one):

```cpp
std::vector<int> z;

// bunch of code

do { 

    // bunch of code

    double v_size = v.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < v_size; i++) {
        z.push_back(v[i]);
    }
} while (true);
```

This does work, but my understanding is that its bad programming practise and may get some bizarre results on different compilers. I also get an error message (on the line where the `push_back` is):

> ```
> Implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to
> 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::size_type' (aka
> 'unsigned long')
> ```

I am really new to C++ and coding in general. So, if there are any veterans here, willing to help or figure this out, it would be highly appreciated.

Here is some additional code in more context to clarify:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::vector<int> z;
    
    int option;
    std::cout << "Enter option";
    std::cin >> option;
    
    do {
        double v_size = v.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < v_size; i++) {
            z.push_back(v[i]);
        }

        // Clearing vector v to let the loop run again, and the vector
        // need to be empty for the real code to work.
        v.clear();
    } while (option != 1);
    
    // Use the vector Z for all the total values that
    // circled through vector v.
}
```

Comment: You want `size_t v_size = v.size();` instead of `double v_size = v.size();`, and that doesn't have anything to do with the problem you state in your question title. Regarding the `z.push_back(v[i]);` we cannot tell without knowing the concrete types used to instantiate those vectors.

Comment: To copy a vector just do: `std::vector<T> z = v;`, replacing `T` with whatever type your vector holds.

Comment: I'm rather confused what you are really doing here. Copying a vector is done via the `operator=` usually, why do you have a loop here?

Comment: `std::vector<T> z (v)` is also an option.

Comment: Hard to understand the code above, or what you're actually trying to do, but undoubtedly it's possible to copy a vector to use it somewhere else. And copying a vector is done with `z = w;` not with a loop.

Comment: @Unholy I suspect OP used different types for the vector instantiations. Something like `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<double>`

Comment: How much of the vector do you want to copy? There are a wide variety of solutions. The `=` operator for the whole thing, constructors, `std::copy`, and `insert` for well-defined ranges. `std::copy_if` when you one some but not all based on the values. Loops if you don't really know when you're going to stop...

Comment: _@user14350967_ It's time to show us a [mcve] as required here, including all relevant code and error / warning messages.

Comment: Side note: You don't want to compare for exact equality with `float`, `double`, or any other floating point number. Floating point numbers are not precise and you often wind up with a number like 1.000000000000001 or 0.999999999999 causing the test to fail. You have to test for "Close enough" with an epsilon value that defines what close enough means.

Comment: Side note: Once a different value than `1` is entered as `option` the loop will loop forever, unless there's some `break;` in it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think this question needs a better title but I can't think of one

Comment: @AryanParekh Or the OP needs to better explain, what their real problem is. I am pretty sure that the mentioned warning doesn't appear with the `push_back()`.

Comment: Consider acctping *the* answer since you have asked the question 11 days ago

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to compare `int` and `double`;

if you are trying to copy the contents of one vector into another. What you are doing is not the best way.

There are a few methods

Source: [**Ways to copy a vector into another in C++**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-copy-vector-c/)

### Using the `=` operator

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec1{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> vec2 = vec1;
```

### Passing vector by a constructor

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec1{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> vec2(vec1);
```

### Using `std::copy`

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec1{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> vec2;
std::copy(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), back_inserter(vec2));
```

### `assign`

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec1{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> vec2;
vec2.assign(vec1.begin(), vec1.end());
```

## Iterating through a vector

Just some extra knowledge I believe can help you

Maybe you already know this, maybe you don't. But iterating through a vector the way you have mentioned is also not the best and there is a better way.

[**C++11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) Introduced [Range-based loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). A nicer and cleaner way to iterate over a range of values.

### Syntax

It goes like this
`for ( range_declaration : range_expression )`

in context to our example

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec{4,62,36,54};
for (auto i:vec){
    std::cout << i;
}
```

---

If you don't want to modify the values, it is a good practice to use
`const auto i:vec` rather than `auto i:vec`. Check [this out for more information](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: Alright, I understand that I am not supposed to copy the vector in such away. But the code loops so it needs to add the first vector to the second vector for basically as many times as it needs to. I don't achieve that with the normal ways, when I copy it in a normal way, the rest of the code cant the new vector inside of my loop...

Comment: @user14350967 `std::copy(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), back_inserter(vec2));` basically achieves addition to "output" vector. And you can clear your original vector at end of loop

Comment: @user14350967 If you want to remember the original values, just do the copy before you enter the loop?